# Accessing a home server locally and remotely form the same hostname

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, home-server

I have a home server (Ubuntu 20.04) that I use for development, video encoding and other server related tasks that I want to be able to access locally or remotely from the same hostname.

Right now when at home I connect with its LAN IP address `192.168.1.200`.
I have configured a Wireguard VPN to access it remotely using an IP address like `10.0.0.2`

This all works well with the problem being that I have to switch which IP address I am connecting to depending on whether I am at home or not.

I have a Windows laptop that I would like to be able to connect to the home server using the same hostname whether at home or away and have it resolve to the LAN address when on the home network, and resolve the server's VPN IP address when on a different network. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You need to control DNS in both places, and you need DNS to provide different answers based on where you are.  There are a few ways to do that.

Comment: My idea as to setup a DNS server on the laptop, but I don't know where to go from there

Answer (score 1):

Resolving over the internet:

1. You have a dynamic WAN IP: You'll want to make use of "Dynamic DNS" ([DDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS)). These services will allow you to install a small client in your LAN network that keeps a DNS server updated with your current IP. This will allow you to make contact with your server from the outside to a normal name. Some routers have built in support for DDNS.
2. You have a fixed WAN IP: Setup your DNS entries at your registrar to point to your fixed IP. If you just want the name to resolve correctly, set the A record (or AAAA record for IPv6)

Resolving in LAN:

If you do not setup DNS in your LAN, you can run into trouble with routers not supporting "NAT Loopback" (also called [hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning)). If your router does support nat loopback, you dont have to setup anything locally.

On the LAN side, setup a DNS server or forwarder or configure your routers DNS server to resolve myserver.mydomain.com to resolve to 192.168.1.200 If you want to setup your own DNS server, i suggest looking at dnsmasq. Dont setup a DNS server on the laptop.